# how to rig the eyebrows which are separate from the head?

Tags: rigging, rigify, makehuman

I imported character from makehuman, and rigged it using rigify, but the eyebrows and eyelashes are separate objects, I don't know how to rig them. should I join them to the head, or parent them to head bone or what.

I am stuck, need your advice.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can do both, either select the separated eyebrow and parent it to the eyebrow bone, or join it to the face mesh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and rig the face as usual, and then weight paint the geometry. *However, in terms of proper deformation I guess the second option might provide more control.*